# clang-query: Examining name of template parameter of a function argument's type

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

I have a big project, and a slew of C++ class member functions of the form:

```cpp
Return CClass::MemberFunction(
   Arg1 arg1,
   //...
   std::weak_ptr<IMemberFunctionListenerInterface> listener) {
//...
}
```

I'm trying to write a matcher that finds functions like these, which have arguments whose types have the string "Listener" in their name.

I can find functions with arguments whose types have "`weak_ptr`" in their name:

```
clang-query> m cxxMethodDecl(hasAnyParameter(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(matchesName("weak_ptr")))))
```

This matches the above function just fine. But if I change `"weak_ptr"` to `"Listener"`, the function is no longer matched. I'm guessing this is because it is the name of a template parameter to the `std::weak_ptr` class template.

I've tried a lot of different variations of this query, but I haven't hit on the one that matches the functions I'm interested in.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one line:

```
clang-query> m cxxMethodDecl(hasAnyParameter(hasType(allOf(cxxRecordDecl(matchesName("weak_ptr")), classTemplateSpecializationDecl(hasTemplateArgument(0, templateArgument(refersToType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(matchesName(".*Listener")))))))))))
```

clang-formatted:

```
cxxMethodDecl(hasAnyParameter(
    hasType(allOf(cxxRecordDecl(matchesName("weak_ptr")),
                  classTemplateSpecializationDecl(hasTemplateArgument(
                      0, templateArgument(refersToType(hasDeclaration(
                             cxxRecordDecl(matchesName(".*Listener")))))))))))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The `hasDeclaration` was the bit that I never tried in all my blind flailings. And replacing `hasTemplateArgument(0, ...)` with `hasAnyTemplateArgument(...)` gets me the rest of the way.

Comment: `weak_ptr` only has one template argument.

Comment: clang-query's context-sensitive tab-completion is helpful for seeing what you can match next, and use `anything()` to check you're on the right track.